# Дискорд бот не проверяет сообщения. Что не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import os
import discord
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_ready():
  print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def on_message(message):
  
  if message.author == client.user:
    print('message checked, denied')
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith(';hello'):
    print('message checked')
    await message.channel.send('hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо пустую строку между функцией и декоратором убрать (так лучше читается), а на вторую функцию декоратор добавить (а это уже обязательно).

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # ...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...
```

Кажется, все? Если верить [минимальному примеру из документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), который точь точь, как ваш - то да, все.

Comment: Спасибо большое